# trouble forcing tds in same table to have same width

Tags: css, html

I'm having a bit of difficulty making the td width all the same
so I tried table-layout: fixed and it didnt work 
any other suggestions?

Comment: Where is your code? Provide some.. all TD:s in same column have always same width. The content width can differ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to say that you want each column in your table to have the same width?  If so, you can either specify a specific width such as:

```
td { width: 100px; }
```

Or you could calculate the width as percentages, so if you have 5 columns each td would be 20%, etc.  A 4-column table would be:

```
td {width: 25%; }
```